# suppressing react hydration errors for third-party components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using a **React** component being exported from an external library (within `node_modules`).

This component works completely fine but will *always* throw a server-client mismatch error on mount:

> Warning: Prop `aria-label` did not match. Server: "June 26, 2023" Client: "26 June 2023"

This error is out of my control as it is being thrown by one of the component's children, preventing me from using `suppressHydrationWarning`.

On a small scale, this wouldn't be much of an issue, but I'm using this component at length in my app, and thus it results in a rather difficult-to-debug console.

How do I suppress *this* warning for *only for this component* from my own project?